# ASP.NET MVC 5 app on IIS throws 500 - Internal server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, controller

I'm getting a 550-internal server error on all pages from a specific controller. All of the other views from other controllers gives the specific view.

The controller a simple controller with CRUD functionality.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Supervisor, Ploeg")]
public class DienstbulletinController : Controller
{
    private readonly DienstbulletinAppContext _db = new DienstbulletinAppContext();

    // GET: Dienstbulletin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var dienstbulletin = _db.Dienstbulletins.Where(a => a.Deleted == false).Include(d => d.Obp)
            .Include(d => d.Ogp).Include(d => d.Opsteller).Include(d => d.Ploeg).Include(d => d.Rechercheur)
            .Include(d => d.Voertuig);
        var data = dienstbulletin.ToList();
        return View(data.OrderByDescending(a => a.Datum.Date).ThenByDescending(a => a.ID).ToList());
    }

    // GET: Dienstbulletin/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        var dienstbulletin = _db.Dienstbulletins.Find(id);
        if (dienstbulletin == null) return HttpNotFound();
        return View(dienstbulletin);
    }

    // GET: Dienstbulletin/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {            
       Dienstbulletin dienstbulletin = new Dienstbulletin ()

        return View(dienstbulletin);
    }
}
```

in the routes are following declared

```
 var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings {AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent};
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            "login", // Route name
            "Gebruiker/Login", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Gebruiker", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );

        routes.MapRoute(
                           name: "Default",
                           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                           defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Any idea on what could be wrong with this controller?

In the eventlog on the server is no message or hint found.

Comment: Please post the complete error page.

Comment: According to your descritpion, we need to know the details error message for your 500 error. i suggest you could disable the custom error to see the details error message. Besides, you could try to open your server's event viewer and locate the application tag to check the detail 500 error los.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 errors are unhandled exceptions or configuration errors. I guess one of your DB queries or creating your DienstbulletinAppContext throws an exception. And there are several places you can look for it.

During development you can open the browsers debugging tools and take a look at the failed request's response. Usually the respones is a HTML page showing the execption message.

On the server you can look at the IIS logs.

[image]
You should find your logs in folders that are named by your W3SVC site ID numbers. There you can see a subcode describing what happened. But you won't see exception details.

Exceptions leading to a 500 error are mostly warnings in the Windows Application EventLog. The first time I had a 500, I just looked for errors in the log, not for warnings. Did you check for warnings?

Comment: The first paragraph can be wrong as 500.19 is strictly IIS specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a 500.19 error, I recommend to check your app folder acls and web.config. I think the folder need Read & execute access rights for local IIS_IUSRS gloup  to read web.config with IIS. Because 500.19 error is a config problem.